# Key error: count

Tags: pandas

I get the above mentioned error in this problem. Can anyone please help me correct it?

Example data frame: column `ID` with 3 numbers and column `count` with 3 numbers.

If `key='count'`, the sum of the values in the `count` value will be obtained. If `key='ID'`, the sum of the values in the `ID` column will be summed.

Current code:

```
def sum_column(X,key='count'):
   S = X[key].sum()
   return S
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand from your code, your [dictionary](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) `X` does not contain values for the key `count`. You can set a value for `count` by invoking a line similar to `X['count']=1`. Now you will need to find out why this is the case (maybe a typo?). If you require more understanding of the problem, you might want to check out [this page about KeyErrors](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/).

Nevertheless, these types of questions are not solely related to Data Science, thus you may want to ask on a platform with a larger user base like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). This is also stated in the [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).